# Gremlin - Move multiple edges in single traversal

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am using Gremlin to access data in AWS Neptune. I need to modify 2 edges going out from a single vertex to point to 2 vertices which are different from the ones it points to at the moment.

For instance if the current relation is as shown below:

```
(X)---(A)---(Y)
   (B)   (C)
```

I want it to modified to:

```
(X)   (A)   (Y)
     /   \
   (B)   (C)
```

To ensure the whole operation is done in a single transaction, I need this done in a single traversal (because [manual transaction logic using `tx.commit()` and `tx.rollback()` is not supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html) in AWS Neptune).

I tried the following queries to get this done but failed:

1) Add the new edges and drop the previous ones by selecting them using alias:

```
g.V(<id of B>).as('B').V(<id of C>).as('C').V(<id of A>).as('A').outE('LINK1','LINK2')
.as('oldEdges').addE('LINK1').from('A').to('B').addE('LINK2').from('A').to('C')
.select('oldEdges').drop();
```

Here, since `outE('LINK1','LINK2')` returns 2 edges, the edges being added after it, executes twice. So I get double the number of expected edges between A to B and C.

2) Add the new edges and drop the existing edges where edge id not equal to newly added ones.

```
g.V(<id of B>).as('B').V(<id of C>).as('C').V(<id of A>).as('A')
.addE('LINK1').from('A').to('B').as('edge1').addE('LINK2').from('A').to('C').as('edge2')
.select('A').outE().where(__.hasId(neq(select('edge1').id()))
.and(hasId(neq(select('edge2').id())))).drop();
```

Here I get the following exception in my gremlin console:

`could not be serialized by org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal.class);
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.getRegistration(Kryo.java:488)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.AbstractGryoClassResolver.writeClass(AbstractGryoClassResolver.java:110)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.writeClass(Kryo.java:517)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:622)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.shaded.ShadedKryoAdapter.writeClassAndObject(ShadedKryoAdapter.java:49)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.shaded.ShadedKryoAdapter.writeClassAndObject(ShadedKryoAdapter.java:24)
...`

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
g.V(<id of A>).union(
    addE('Link1').to(V(<id of B>)),
    addE('Link2').to(V(<id of C>)),
    outE('Link1', 'Link2').where(inV().hasId(<id of X>,<id of Y>)).drop()
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped. Although this query can only be used when both the edges are to be modified (not when either one on none has a change, but I had not mentioned that in the question).